# My robot process automation script fails when executed through local Jenkins but works fine when run through console

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, robotframework

```
Framework=Robot Process Automation
IDE=Pycharm
Libary= mutliple libabaries selenium, robotframework etc.
```

I have written a simple script to identify a web element (input text box) through a locater.
The locator can be xpath,name or id.

THe script works fine when executed through the console but fails when executed through Jenkins.If  I remove these locators my scripts works fine in Jenkins (installed on the local machine). I tried to install selenium plugin in Jenkins but still same error. In Jenkins I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_name'
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

Below is my script that fails

```
** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}  https://login

${browser}      Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
open browser      ${url}    ${browser}
    sleep  10
   input text   name:username     Admin
    sleep  10
   input text   xpath://body/div[@id='app']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]        admin123
    sleep  10
```

(I am adding sleep to ensure its not the timing issue.)

The below script works fine in Jenkins

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}  https://
${browser}      Chrome
*** Test Cases ***
PageTitle
    open browser      ${url}    ${browser}
    sleep  2
    title should be   Robot Framework
    close browser
```

Initially I was getting the same error in console but then I installed selenium version 3.3.0 in PhyCharm IDE and it resolved the problem at the console-level

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because it's using a newer version of `selenium`, which removed some deprecated methods, such as `find_elements_by_name` and `find_elements_by_xpath` in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use the following methods for your situation:

```py
driver.find_elements("name", NAME)
```

or

```py
driver.find_elements("xpath", XPATH_SELECTOR)
```

Comment: Don't think so this is the case. As mentioned I am using Selenium Library 3.3.0.Also I am not using the method driver. find_element(). My scripts pass in PhyCharm terminal.

Comment: It it possible that you have different virtual environments in use. Are you able to print out ``selenium.__version__`` after you ``import selenium`` to confirm the version before the part where the script fails?

Comment: The version of Selenium is 3.3.0. If its a deprecated method issue, then the script should not work in PhyCharm terminal.

Comment: If the version on Pycharm is older than the one in the Jenkins environment, then those deprecated methods would still work. If you try the updated versions, `driver.find_elements("name", NAME)` and `driver.find_elements("xpath", XPATH_SELECTOR)`, then those should work in all environments.